# How to download jq offline execution file

Tags: linux, centos, jq, yum

My project needs to parse json through `jq`. In order to ensure that the machine where the service is located can run, I copied the jq installed by yum to the project directory, but when I used the project rpm to install, the following error occurred

```
rpm -ivh /tmp/xxx.rpm
Stderr: error: Failed dependencies:
        libjq.so.1()(64bit) is needed by xxx.rpm
        libonig.so.5()(64bit) is needed by xxx.rpm
```

This should be caused by `jq`, because the previous version didn't use it but installed successfully.

Is there an offline version available without dependencies?

> nc doesn't seem to have this problem.

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Get a statically linked binary from github: https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.6